# when i get the user using the "ExecutionContext.switchToHttp().getRequest()" method, it always brings me the same user

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, nestjs, refresh-token

I have an authentication application where I implement jwt with access token and refreshtoken, when I try to refresh the token it always fails because as I commented in the title, when I get the user using the "ExecutionContext.switchToHttp().getRequest()" method, it always brings me the same user and therefore compares the refresh token of another user that is stored in the mongodb database against that of the current user, which is another.

I attach the link of the code so you can see it better: https://github.com/lucianopulido/auth

Answer (score 0):

jwt auth with node and ts:

accessToken.strategy.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

type JwtPayload = {
  sub: string;
  email: string;
};
@Injectable()
export class AccessTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

refreshToken.strategy.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class RefreshTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  Strategy,
  'jwt-refresh',
) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY,
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  validate(req: Request, payload: any) {
    const refreshToken = req.get('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '').trim();
    return { ...payload, refreshToken };
  }
}
```

//Use this guard in any protected endpoint

accessToken.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class AccessTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

// use this guard only in /refresh endpoint

refreshToken.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class RefreshTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt-refresh') {}
```

//To get users info in endpoint

userDecorator.ts:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;

    return data ? user?.[data] : user;
  },
);
```

refresh endpoint:

controller:

```
@UseGuards(RefreshTokenGuard)
  @Get('/refresh')
  refresh(
    @Req() req,
    @CurrentUser('userId') id: string,
    @CurrentUser('refreshToken') refreshToken: string,
  ) {
    return this.authService.refreshTokens(id, refreshToken);
  }
```

service:

```
async refreshTokens(userId: string, refreshToken: string) {
    // check if user exist & has refresh
    const user = await this.usersService.findUserById(userId);
    if (!user || !user.refreshToken) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Access Denied');
    }
    // get new tokens
    const tokens = await this.getTokens(user.id, user.email);
    // update users refresh token
    await this.updateRefreshToken(user.id, tokens.refreshToken);
    return tokens;
  }
```

getTokens function:

```
async getTokens(userId: string, email: string) {
    // create access token
    const accessToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync(
      {
        userId,
        email,
      },
      {
        secret: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
        expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES,
      },
    );

    // create refresh token
    const refreshToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync(
      {
        userId,
        email,
      },
      {
        secret: process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY,
        expiresIn: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES,
      },
    );

    return {
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
    };
  }
```

endpoint example:

```
@Get('/protected-endpoint')
  @UseGuards(AccessTokenGuard)
  async protected(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
    @CurrentUser('id') id: string,
  ) {
...
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, that doesn't answer my question